# How to search for a pattern at the end of the line in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am trying to search for the following patterns at the end of the line using **Notepad++**.

```
e-08 E
```

or

```
e-08 A
```

I tried the following in extended and Regular expression search modes but the end-of-line causes issues.

```
e-0[0-8]\s[EA]\n
```

I also tried the following which works so I am only missing the end-of-line

```
e-0[0-8]\s[EA]
```

Answer (score 0):

When using regex, $ matches end of line. You can modify your regular expression to

```
e-0[0-8]\s[EA]$
```